# Stop elastic search tokenizing a query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter out some documents in elastic search 8.4.  The issue I'm having is something like this...

```
must_not: [
    match: { ingredients: { query : 'peanut butter' } }
]
```

seems to break the query into 'peanut' and 'butter'.  Then, documents which contain the ingredient 'butter' get incorrectly filtered.  Is there a way to prevent this tokenizing without defining a custom analyzer?  Or perhaps a different way to search to get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to filter documents with just "peanut" or "butter" you need to use the ["and" operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#match-field-params). In this way only documents with "peanut butter" will be filtered.

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must_not": [
         {
           "match": {
             "ingredients": {
               "query": "peanut butter",
               "operator": "and"
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```